# Check before setting constant?

Tags: php, constants

Is it better to check whether a constant exists before setting it? Or is it ok to just set it directly? I am creating a WordPress plugin and setting a few constants, I've seen some plugins that set them directly and others check via if !(defined)

Comment: You can override globals yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If you may reasonably expect the constant to already exist, then you should check. If you are sure the constant must not exist at this point because you need to define it, you should not check and let PHP fail hard if your expectation is not met. Errors help to pinpoint problems.

Answer (score 1):

If the whole project is under your control, then you could just define the constant without checking it (because you should know whether it exists).

But for developing a wordpress plugin, you need to prevent the constant conflict with other constant defined in other plugins, you need to check it first.